# How to bind with static actions like buttons, dropdowns, inputs with FooTable V3?

Tags: footable

**FooTable V3** comes with pagination, filtering and sorting controls within it self. I have **"Custom dropdown"** and **"Custom search"** that required but out of the FooTable controls. I am new to FooTable V3. Can someone guide me how to bind it. Here is my test demo:

jsfiddle.net/claudchan/gup20y3v/2/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

My issue is solved. below is the answer from @steveush:

[Answer](https://github.com/fooplugins/FooTable/issues/613#issuecomment-285602890)

```
jsfiddle.net/gup20y3v/4/
```